# Why does sbt console not see packages from subproject in multi-module project?

Tags: scala, sbt

This is my **project/Build.scala**:

```
package sutils

import sbt._
import Keys._

object SutilsBuild extends Build {

  scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.0"

  val scalazVersion = "7.0.6"

  lazy val sutils = Project(
    id = "sutils",
    base = file(".")
  ).settings(
    test := { },
    publish := { }, // skip publishing for this root project.
    publishLocal := { }
  ).aggregate(
    core
  )

  lazy val core = Project(
    id = "sutils-core",
    base = file("sutils-core")
  ).settings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" % "scalaz-core_2.10" % scalazVersion
  )
}
```

This seems to be compiling my project just fine, but when I go into the console, I can't import any of the code that just got compiled?!

```
$ sbt console
scala> import com.github.dcapwell.sutils.validate.Validation._
<console>:7: error: object github is not a member of package com
       import com.github.dcapwell.sutils.validate.Validation._
```

What am I doing wrong here? Trying to look at the usage, I don't see a way to say which subproject to load while in the console

```
$ sbt about
[info] Loading project definition from /src/sutils/project
[info] Set current project to sutils (in build file:/src/sutils/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1
[info] The current project is {file:/src/sutils/}sutils 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] Available Plugins: org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

Comment: You can always write `sbt sutils/console`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's the solution from @Alexey-Romanov to start the `console` task in the project the classes to import are in.

```
sbt sutils/console
```

There's however another solution that makes the root `sutils` project *depend on* the other `core`. Use the following snippet to set up the project - note `dependsOn core` that will bring the classes from the `core` project to `sutils`'s namespace.

```
lazy val sutils = Project(
  id = "sutils",
  base = file(".")
).settings(
  test := { },
  publish := { }, // skip publishing for this root project.
  publishLocal := { }
).aggregate(
  core
).dependsOn core
```

BTW, you should really use a simpler `build.sbt` for your use case as follows:

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.0"

val scalazVersion = "7.0.6"

lazy val sutils = project.in(file(".")).settings(
  test := {},
  publish := {}, // skip publishing for this root project.
  publishLocal := {}
).aggregate(core).dependsOn(core)

lazy val core = Project(
  id = "sutils-core",
  base = file("sutils-core")
).settings(
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % scalazVersion
)
```

You could make it even easier when you'd split the build to two `build.sbt`s, each for the projects.

Comment: if you already started sbt without specifying the project then you can switch to it inside the SBT REPL with the `project` command